# incremental sum over rows and columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is this the right code:

```
    for i in range len(df):
        df.iloc[i:,0:i]
```

I want to add the values by incrementing the rows and columns like
this:

```
[1:,0:1],
[2:,0:2],
[3:,0:3].. and so on until the length of df.
```

Input:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| B | 5 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| C | 4 | 5 | 0 | 4 |
| D | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 |

Output:

|  | Col1 |
| --- | --- |
| colA and rowB:D | 11 |
| colA:B and rowC:D | 14 |
| colA:C and rowD:D | 9 |

Comment: please dont post pictures of code ...

Comment: Its not the code, its just the table of data

Comment: `numpy.cumsum` i guess is a good place for you to start looking

Comment: Is the dataframe in quadratic form? Meaning same number of columns and rows? Otherwise it will not work like this.

Comment: yes its in matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I wrote and its working:

```
for i in range (len(df)):
  sumAll=df.iloc[i:,0:i].sum()#summ all columns in order
  sumlist=sumAll.tolist()#convert to list
  FinalSum=sum(sumlist)
  NewList.append(str(FinalSum))
```

Comment: Just wanted to check if there is more efficient way

Comment: Can you add sample input and expected output to your question?

Comment: I have added the tables

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,-1))
[np.sum(df.iloc[i:, 0:i].to_numpy()) for i in range(len(df))]
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 50, 93, 111, 86]
```